# Split String in SHell

Tags: shell, debian

I have a string with IP address:

`172.27.16.123`

I have a similar second string.

I need the four parts in four distinct variables i.e. v1=172, v2=27,v3=16,v4=123
The reason I want to this is that I want to take a third ip and see if it lies inbetween these two ips

I tried

```
echo $givenip | cut -d\. -f3
```

Comment: some details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/split-string-based-on-delimiter-in-bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export v1=`echo $givenip | cut -d\. -f3`
```

Comment: How could I use this if my delimiter character is a space? If i try: echo $var | cut -d\ -f3, or echo $var | cut -d\' ' -f3 is doesn't work. First one it says delimiter must be only one char, and the second one changes my Prompt to ">".

Comment: `export v1=`echo $givenip | cut -d" " -f3`

Answer (score 0):

v11=$(echo $ip1 | cut -d. -f3)

echo $v11

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your shell is `bash`, you should probably use arrays:

```
givenip=172.27.18.191
ip1=( $(sed 's/\./ /g' <<< 172.27.16.123) )
ip2=( $(sed 's/\./ /g' <<< 172.27.19.254) )
ip3=( $(sed 's/\./ /g' <<< $givenip) )
```

Then you can compare components:

```
givenip=172.27.18.191
ip1=( $(sed 's/\./ /g' <<< 172.27.16.123) )
ip2=( $(sed 's/\./ /g' <<< 172.27.19.254) )
ip3=( $(sed 's/\./ /g' <<< $givenip) )

if [ "${ip3[0]}" -ge "${ip1[0]}" -a "${ip3[0]}" -le "${ip2[0]}" ] &&
   [ "${ip3[1]}" -ge "${ip1[1]}" -a "${ip3[1]}" -le "${ip2[1]}" ] &&
   [ "${ip3[2]}" -ge "${ip1[2]}" -a "${ip3[2]}" -le "${ip2[2]}" ] &&
   [ "${ip3[3]}" -ge "${ip1[3]}" -a "${ip3[3]}" -le "${ip2[3]}" ]
 then echo $givenip is between two established IP addresses
 else echo $givenip is not between the two established IP addresses
 fi
```